# Any node.js example with mongo db where user integration is done?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am a complete newbie in node.js/express/mongodb stack in creating a REST api. Though the tutorials have been rather helpful to get me started, I find myself completely stuck when it comes to applying authorization/authentication to the api. Any examples as such would be really helpful. I've gone through connect and passport but there isn't a good example of an app where a user login/sign up(with authentication) + skeletal rest api to access data of the user is given. It would be rather awesome if anything like that can be provided?

Thank you!

Comment: this might not be extremely recent. but seems it's what you're looking for: http://dailyjs.com/2010/12/06/node-tutorial-5/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of authentication using `passportjs` 
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/examples/login/app.js

Hopefully this may help you.
For using it with `mongodb` do retrieve all the records and store it in array using the `toArray()` method.For eg in the code snippet in the example just modify it as

```
findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
     db.collections.find().toArray(function(err,user){
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + username }); }
        if (user.password != password) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' }); }
        return done(null, user);
      })
    });
  }
});
));
```